# VS Code + React + JSX + Components props intellisense is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, reactjs

I have a project using .JS and it works perfectly for React Components, but with my other project that I'm using JSX as file extension, it's not working.

I found some similar issues, but I couldn't fix it doing what I supposed to do and I'm still with the problem.

When I press F12 to go to the definition of the component, I get this message:

[image]

And when I start to write a prop, the intellisense doesn't show the prop definition. Not even the prop name. And it works with .JS files like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason react types choose when they want to be installed

Run

```sh
npm install @types/react
```

And you should be fine

Comment: @types are used with Typescript, and they didn't mention they're using TS.

Comment: I had the same issue while using the JavaScript version. This solved it. So far I haven’t come across this issue with typescript